# MySQL stored procedure OUT param returned as null (NO LOCAL VARIABLE DECLARED)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, null, return-value

I am trying to debug this problem. I've gone to great extremes and am just trying to figure out why MySQL will return null even when the return var is explicitly set to some value.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `foo`(
    OUT numberExpectedToFill int(11))
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

    set numberExpectedToFill := 23;
    commit;
 END
```

So, I scripted a little script to call it, and the return value is NULL. Why?

```
prepare s from 'call `test_schema`.`foo`(@output)';
execute s;
select @output
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most unexpected ... as this works in sqlfiddle both with and without using a prepared statement: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4ddf/1, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4ddf/2

Maybe is there a problem with the permissions (would probably signal an error, thought) ?!?

EDIT: still *guessing* -- are you sure to call `foo` from the right schema? O_o

Comment: Ah, you are right. So stupid. I have several versions of the schema and had the wrong one. My eyes are not working.